# default NTFS permissions on NetApp CIFS share

Tags: cifs, share, netapp

Basic premise is that I've created a share and permissioned it up and I can't then change permissions, or even create a folder in it.

Volume:
/vol/ProjectData

Share
/vol/ProjectData  as  \netappfiler\Projects

inside OnCommand System Manager I've assigned a domain group for which i am a member as having full control.
I expected these to pass through as share permissions and for this to then allow me to set ntfs permissions from computer management on my 8.1 laptop.

so on the share:
Everyone - Read
Team-Name - Full control

open up windows 8.1 Computer Management, connect to another computer, connect to the Filer

When I try and save the changes I make to the NTFS permissions, I get access is denied.
I've seen this article https://www.pickysysadmin.ca/2012/04/27/access-denied-when-changing-ntfs-permissions-on-a-netapp-cifs-share-from-windows…
and i wondered if it was something similar. so i used Computer Management on xp and it came back with the same error.

Am I setting my shares up wrongly? Have I missed some super basic config concept out here?

I did however add a qtree to the Share and all of a sudden (inside the qtree) I could create text files and documents.
So have I misunderstood the way it works? If I want to permission at NTFS levels, do i need to build something like the following?
/vol/Volume/Qtree and then create a share at the Qtree level?

Comment: Can you check whether the volume is set to NTFS security style?

Comment: do you mean volume? there are no options for permissions styles that I can see in system manager.

Comment: Right click the volume, edit, and check whether it's set to Unix. If so, change it to NTFS.

Comment: they're set to mixed currently. ill create a new one and set it up as NTFS and do some testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never have volumes or qtrees set to mixed security. Pick either NTFS or UNIX and use that. If you want to be able to have a CIFS shares to a folder with permissions, use NTFS. If you need both concurrent CIFS and NFS connections, pick NTFS. If it's a LUN or a NFS share, pick UNIX.

If you right click a volume in the gui and edit, you should see an option for "security style". This is referring to the default qtree on the volume. Security is a property of a qtree, and each volume contains at least the default qtree. If you have other qtrees, they can be set to anything. NTFS and UNIX in the same volume.

Comment: somehow id missed the suggestion in the second paragraoh. twas the solution, so thanks for taking the time to answer such a noob question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `man qtree` you'll see there's an option for `qtree security` with a choice of NTFS, Unix or mixed. You'll need to ensure it's set to NTFS.

Comment: but does it actually need the qtree is the question I'm asking.